# GoogleSheets Conditional Format based on formula in the current Cell

Tags: google-sheets

I have tried the following as the Conditional Formatting Custom Formula:
Where B2 is the current cell:

```
COUNT(FIND("$B$1",FormulaText(B2)))>=1
```

the formula in B2 is A2*$B$1 in B3 is A3*$B$1  etc. - but some cells do not reference B1

If I paste this into a cell/range in column C:

```
=COUNT(FIND("$B$1",FormulaText(B2)))>=1
```

then it correctly returns true or false depending on the formula in the adjoining cell.

However when applied as a conditional format it is not changing the format of cell B2

I also want this formula to apply to a range of cells - but it seems to apply the identical formula COUNT(FIND("$B$1",FormulaText(B2)))>=1 to each cell and not change B2 to B3, B4, B5 etc.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: It works for me.  Is there a chance you have another CF  formatting rule of higher priority, ie. above that rule?  Here is my sample sheet...  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yPrVzoSAGN10yXpdNFrL4S7lg614s3m5g0RN-1Oa2w8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you @kirkg13 - in particular for sharing the sheet which I should have done.  There is one tiny difference and that is the range of cells - I had applied the formula to a range in column B and you applied to the range to both columns A & B - all resolved and thank you

Answer (score 0):

Thank you you to @kirkg - this is resolved simply by applying the format to a range in both columns A&B:
Here is his sample sheet... docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/… – kirkg13